# How do I populate an array of objects where every object has an array inside of it using response from rest API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, vuejs2

I can't google the right solution for this for about an hour straight,
So I'm getting a response from the API that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "name1",
    "Title": "Name One",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Name": "Name 1.1",
        "Title": "Name one point one"
      },
     ]
```

And I need it to fit this kind of "mold" for the data to fit in:

```
{
title: 'Name One',
value: 'name1',
key: '1',
children: [
  {
    title: 'Name one point one',
    value: 'Name 1.1',
    key: 'key1',
  },
```

I am trying to achieve this using a foreach but It's not working as intended because I need to do this all in one instance of a foreach.
Here's what I gave a go to(vue2):

```
   created() {
    getData().then(response => {
      const formattedResponse = []
      response.forEach((el, key) => {
        formattedResponse.title = response.Title
        formattedResponse.name = response.Name
        formattedResponse.children = response.Children
      })
    })
```

Comment: Where did `title: 'Name 1'` and `title: 'Child Node1'` come from?

Comment: Please _show us_ what you tried, and give a proper problem description along with it. Just telling us _that_ you tried something, isn't helpful.

Comment: And why/how did two children become a single one, by what logic is that supposed to happen?

Comment: Other than the 'key' property, those objects are exactly the same (apart from capitalisation).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the main array and use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the properties by key, and relabel them, and then do exactly the same with the `children` array. Then return the updated array of objects.

```js
const data=[{Name:"name1",Title:"Name One",Children:[{Name:"Name 1.1",Title:"Name one point one"}]},{Name:"name2",Title:"Name Two",Children:[{Name:"Name 1.2",Title:"Name one point two"}]}];

const result = data.map((obj, key) => {

  const { Title: title, Name: value } = obj;
  
  const children = obj.Children.map(obj => {
    const { Title: title, Name: value } = obj;
    return { title, value, key: (key + 1).toString() };
  });
  
  return { title, value, children };
   
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your API response is JSON. All you need to do is:

```
var resp=JSON.parse(API response);
```